# How can I bend legs smoothly?

Tags: rigging

I tried to control it with WEIGHT paint, but I couldn't.
I've also tried Smooth Corrective, but it doesn't work.
What should I do if I bend that legs smoothly?[image]

[image]

Comment: https://youtu.be/2p_ztL5NwaA

Comment: thank you very much :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

try to loop cut.The more mesh, the softer it is.